# httpget not return anything

Tags: android, http-get

I have the function contador2 () which connects to a webservices and returns the data that is in the URL.

The problem is that it doesn't return anything, shows me empty variable repsonse2.

The log shows no exception.

Help please

```
 package com.example.dona1click;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Donar extends Fragment {

    ImageButton insertar;
    String emailAdd;
    String name;
    ImageView x;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    TextView text;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.donar, container, false);


        // Capturo las variables que dejo en memoria, nombre y email

        SharedPreferences sp1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        emailAdd = sp1.getString("EMAILADDRESS", "");
        name = sp1.getString("NAME", "");

        //-----------------------------------------------



        insertar=(ImageButton) x.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        text=(TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setText(contador2());

        insertar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    new Insertar(getActivity()).execute();      

            }

        });


        return x;
    }


    //Captura los datos del contador en el servidor.
    private String contador2(){ 

        // Declaro variables

                    String response2 = "";
                    HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpGet httppget;
                    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpResponse res;
                    HttpEntity ent;

                    //-------------------------



                    httppget= new HttpGet("http://example.com/data.php"); // Url del Servidor a donde se envian las var post




                    try {

                       res = httpclient2.execute(httppget, context);
                       ent = res.getEntity();
                       response2 = EntityUtils.toString(ent);
                       //----------------------------------------------------------------

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }

                    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + response2);
                    return response2;
    }       





//Inserta los datos de las Personas en el servidor.
        private String insertar(){  

            // Declaro variables

            String response = "";
            HttpClient httpclient;
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
            HttpPost httppost;

            //-------------------------

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient(); // abre la conexion con un cliente web

            httppost= new HttpPost("http://example.co/insert.php"); // Url del Servidor a donde se envian las var post

            //Añadimos nuestros datos en un arraylist

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",emailAdd.toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre",name.toString().trim()));

            //---------------------------------------


            try {
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));// envio las variables

               // capturo lo que devuelve, si no devolviera nada solo hago la ejecucion del httpclient sin el handler

               ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
               response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

               //----------------------------------------------------------------

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }       

        //AsyncTask para insertar Personas
        class Insertar extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

            private Activity context;

            Insertar(Activity context){
                this.context=context;
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub


              String result = insertar();



              return result;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); */

                if ( result.equals("0") ){

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
                    alert.setTitle("Dona1Click - Patrocinador");

                    alert.setMessage("Lo sentimos, ha excedido el limite diaro de 20 clicks");

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    alert.show();





                }


                if ( result.equals("1") ){

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
                    alert.setTitle("Dona1Click - Patrocinador");


                    WebView wv = new WebView(getActivity());
                    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
                    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false); 
                    wv.loadUrl("https://www.dona1click.org/core/patro_app_mobile.php");
                    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            if(pd.isShowing()&&pd!=null)
                            {
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }
                        }


                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            view.loadUrl(url);

                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    alert.setView(wv);
                    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });





                    alert.show();

                 // Para colocar un loading

                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Loading...",true);

                    //--------------------------



                }


            }




        }


        //AsyncTask para insertar Personas
                class Contador extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

                    private Activity context;

                    Contador(Activity context){
                        this.context=context;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                      // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                      String result = "";

                      text.setText(result);

                      return result;
                    }


                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); */



                        }










                }

}
```

Comment: Check you are getting any exception or not. Dont ignore the exception.

Comment: There is not exceptions.

Comment: What was the ent value? If you want to refer a httpget sample, check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321799/android-http-get

Comment: the value in the url is a number in a file .php.

Comment: check my edit, i explain most better the problem. Help me please