# How to download text(String) for use in android app. (using Android Studio)

Tags: android, arrays, string, download

So i need to update information in my app. Currently the info is in a strings.xml file.

My plan is to download the array of strings and save them locally and display it in relevant places.

What i am stuck with is:
I don't know how to get the array from the web. Should it be in a .txt file? 
I have 10 or so Arrays(each containing about 20 elements), will the method i thought of be good for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´d say a common approach would be open a HttpUrlConnection, make a Http Get request, buffer response in Stream and parse as JSON Array. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321799/android-http-get)

Then you can access the datafields of the JSONArray/Object. Would require that your Webservice responses with your array json encoded.

Comment: That should do it. Thanks

Comment: mind accepting my answer then? Thank you ;D