# Getting IllegalArgumentException in my doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, urlencode, illegalargumentexception

I have made a demo in android, and I'm making a http request to an API. I have made an asynctask for making http request. When I make the request to the API, the app crashed and in logcat it says "illegalargumentException" in my request. I am not getting why it is happening.

```
**reqUrl = "http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/itin?_type=json&cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=gs28w3m7nqd8y4gsa4x5qsfs&locale="
                        + Consts.Locale
                        + "&currencyCode="
                        + Consts.currencyCode
                        + "&xml=<HotelItineraryRequest><itineraryId>"
                        + itrny
                        + "</itineraryId><email>"
                        + mail
                        + "</email></HotelItineraryRequest>";**
```

**asynctask**

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;

            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    responseString = out.toString();

                    out.close();
                } else {
                    // Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Handle problems..
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Handle problems..
            }
            return responseString;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out
                    .println("::::::::::::::::::MY ITERNARY RESAPONSE::::::::::::::"
                            + responseString);
            // Do anything with response..
        }
    }
```

I receive the illegal argument at this line:

```
response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
```

Comment: which line you get illegal argument?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira-    response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));

Comment: your uri[0] is null? check it with log

Comment: try `response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet.setURI(uri[0]));`  You might have to create a request variable.  More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321876).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not executing your `AsyncTask` (`RequestTask`) properly (you forgot to include the way you use it btw)

With your current code, You should be invoking it like this

`new RequestTask().execute(myUrlString);`

**Alternate Solution**

If you're doing that and for some weird reason it's not working, and since you're extending `AsyncTask` with your `RequestTask`, you could make sure 100% you are passing the URI by adding a constructor to your class that receives the URL you want to use, something along these lines:

```
private final String uri;

public RequestTask(String uri) {
  this.uri = uri;
}
```

then on your `doInBackground` method, do:

```
response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(this.uri));
```

that should work for sure... but pay attention to how you are starting your `RequestTask`.