# Retrieve data from services and display in android textview

Tags: android

I am developing one quiz application using .net web services. My services working properly.

I want to fetch the question from service and display at Android side. On button click, the question will be changed like quiz application.

Comment: using httpget or httppost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321799/android-http-get

Comment: You could get by using HTTP Post or Get, there are many libs but in my opinion, you should use Volley...it recommended by Google

Comment: Does it works with SOAP . i am using SOAP object for retrieving the data from my .net web services.